# Как установить/удалить обложку mp3 файла c помощью taglib?

Tags: c++

Вот моя попытка сделать это:

```
    QFile file("C:/Users/User/Desktop/cover1.jpg");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    TagLib::ByteVector image(file.readAll(), file.size());
    file.close();

    TagLib::MPEG::File audioFile("C:/Users/User/Desktop/song.mp3");

    TagLib::ID3v2::Tag* tag = audioFile.ID3v2Tag(true);

    ID3v2::FrameList frames = tag->frameList("APIC");
    ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame* frame = nullptr;

    if (frames.isEmpty())
    {
        frame = new TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame;
        tag->addFrame(frame);
    }
    else
    {
        frame = static_cast<ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame*>(frames.front());
    }

    frame->setMimeType("image/jpeg");
    frame->setPicture(image);

    tag->addFrame(frame);

    audioFile.save();
```

Но во-первых, выходит сообщение в консоль -> `TagLib: A picture frame must contain at least 5 bytes.` . И следом, вылетает ошибка в `tag->~Tag();` Буду рад любым предложениям.

P.S: Но что интересно, когда закрываешь программу после ошибки, картинка на mp3 файл устанавливается корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Происходит повторное уничтожение объекта `frame`.

Попробуйте так:

```
if (frames.isEmpty())
{
    frame = new TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame;
}
else
{
    frame = static_cast<TagLib::ID3v2::AttachedPictureFrame*>(frames.front());
    tag->removeFrame(frame, false);
}

frame->setMimeType("image/jpeg");
frame->setPicture(image);

tag->addFrame(frame);

audioFile.save();
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо!!